# Set position of UIPickerView at bottom even after scroll in ios

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uipickerview

I am trying to show `UIPickerView` on click on `UITextField`. I am using a simple method to show the `picker` as follows:

```
-(void) showPickerView {

    [self.view resignFirstResponder];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.50];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

    CGSize iOSDeviceScreenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if(iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 480){

        CGRect frame = self.picker.frame;
        frame.origin.y = 270;
        self.picker.frame = frame;
        frame = self.toolBar.frame;
        frame.origin.y = 226.0;
        self.toolBar.frame = frame;

    } else if(iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 568){

        CGRect frame = self.picker.frame;
        frame.origin.y = 239.0;
        self.picker.frame = frame;
        frame = self.toolBar.frame;
        frame.origin.y = 195.0;
        self.toolBar.frame = frame;

    }

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

It works great if I have not scrolled down. But when I scroll down, my `picker` is placed on fix position as mentioned in `showPickerView` method. Now how I can manage it that my `picker` appears at bottom every time.

Comment: why are you changing frame = self.toolBar.frame; again y value? and one thing check it an where you are changing frame in delegate methods.

Comment: I am using same frame variable for both, picker and toolBar. I am not changing it in any delegate method. I use this method where ever I have to show pickerView

Comment: just remove the toolbar frame and check it. other than that nothing complex business logic over here.

Comment: o/w take another CGrect for toolbar frame

Comment: toolBar is not effecting the pickerview. I think you didn't get my question dear. It is working fine but only if I have not scrolled down.

Comment: can you share the screen shot it will give clear picture to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Add your pickerview to your window.

**Solution 2:**

Implement the scrollview delegate and adjust the frame continuously.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{


    CGSize iOSDeviceScreenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if(iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 480){

        CGRect frame = self.picker.frame;
        frame.origin.y = 270;
        self.picker.frame = frame;
        frame = self.toolBar.frame;
        frame.origin.y = 226.0;
        self.toolBar.frame = frame;

    } else if(iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 568){

        CGRect frame = self.picker.frame;
        frame.origin.y = 239.0;
        self.picker.frame = frame;
        frame = self.toolBar.frame;
        frame.origin.y = 195.0;
        self.toolBar.frame = frame;

    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can just suppose that you are showing your picker inside of a scroll view, right?
And if so, then your picker frame is relative to UIScrollView, not to a screen view.
So you have to take into account your scroll view offset. Something like that:

```
    CGRect frame = self.picker.frame;
    frame.origin.y = self.scrollvew.contentOffset.y + 270;
```

Otherwise you can show your picker outside of the UIScrollView (just add it to a screen view).

Comment: But it gives same issue if I change contentOffset in textfield delegate.